# Combining two numeric variables with unite and retaining new column as a numeric variable in r

Tags: r, numeric

In trying to use unite to concatenate two numeric columns, I think this is turning the resulting column into a character string - how to avoid this?

```
df  %>% unite(housinggrossconcat, housinggrossedupnet, housing.gross, na.rm=TRUE, remove=FALSE))
                %>% unite(grossconcat, grossedupnet, gross, na.rm=TRUE, remove=FALSE)
```

Data looks like this:

```
Gross    Grossedupnet    New Column: Grossconcat
 30         NA              30
 NA         45              45 
 NA         45              45
 350        NA              350
```

It is such that wherever Gross has a value, Grossedupnet will be NA, and vice versa. They're both numerical values. I want to concatenate the two into the new column, but it is turning the new column into a character variable.

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: I updated my post if that's helpful!

Comment: you can use as.numeric()

Comment: or: Grossconcat <- ifelse(is.na(df$Gross), df$Grossedupnet, df$Gross), in the assumption that the one is always NA when the other is not and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `coalesce`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Grossconcat = coalesce(Gross, Grossedupnet))
```

`dplyr::coalesce()` is built for the purpose of taking the first non-missing value. It works on as many columns as you give it, and it works well for all data types. `unite` is the complement to `separate`. It is for pasting together strings, hence the `character` output.

Comment: Ok great. Can  you explain what you mean when you say 'of taking the first non-missing value'?

Comment: `coalesce(a, b, c)` will, by row, keep the first non-missing value in columns a, b, c, in that order. Your data seems to be exactly complementary - if `a` is missing than `b` is present, and vice versa. But it's common to have cases where `a` and `b` might both have non-missing values, and `coalesce` will prioritize whichever argument you put as the first one.

Comment: `unite`, on the other hand, pastes things together, so if `a` was 10 and `b` was 12, `unite(a,b)` would be `"1012"` - good for strings, bad for numbers.

Comment: Ohh I see. In that case --> in creating the grossedupnet variable, I actually wrote a code that changed any value in there to NA if there was a corresponding value in gross. so I think you are saying that I didn't actually have to do that if I used coalesce?

Comment: here's the code:     rawdata1$net[which(!is.na(rawdata1$gross))] <- NA rawdata1 %>%  mutate(grossedupnet = net * 1.15)  %>% mutate(grossconcat=coalesce(gross, grossedupnet))

Comment: That's correct. All that is simplified to `rawdata1 %>% mutate(grossconcat = coalesce(gross, net * 1.15))`, assuming you don't need `net` saved.

Comment: ahh okay. Wow, that is really helpful to know. Thank you. If I *did* need to save Net, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hmmm, I misspoke. That does save `net`, it just doesn't modify it to be missing when `gross` is present. It's `grossedupnet` that isn't saved. If you need to save that, then `rawdata1 %>% mutate(grossedupnet = net * 1.15, grossconcat = coalesce(gross, grossedupnet))`.

Comment: Gregor, I have a slightly similar question: In these codes, I'm summing a few columns (using objects) into a new column; is there a way to then "move" the columns that are summed into a new dataframe? (instead of saying remove=TRUE) rawdata2$LicenseMonthlyTotal <- rowSums(rawdata2[, c(License)], na.rm=TRUE)
rawdata2$NWAMonthlytotal <- rowSums(rawdata2[,c(NWA)], na.rm=TRUE)
rawdata2$StaffandVolunteersTotal <- rowSums(rawdata2[,c("staff", "volunteers")], na.rm=TRUE)

Comment: Comments aren't a good place for new questions - just ask a new question.

Comment: in combining columns a and b using coalesce, I realized I need to prioritize column b, rather than a, when I combine the two values. here's my code: rawdata2 <- (rawdata2 %>% mutate(Leaseconcat=coalesce(Leasemonthlytotal, Lease_Cost1)) :Leasemonthly is what needs to be prioritized over Lease_Cost1, but in the dataset, Leasemonthlytotal is B and Lease_Cost1 is A - I'm finding that where there's 2 values in both, it's taking Lease_Cost1 over Leasemonthlytotal, because the latter comes first

Comment: Yeah, whichever one you want to prioritize should go first in `coalesce()`. That's what I tried to explain in my first comment on this answer - *"`coalesce(a, b, c)` will, by row, keep the first non-missing value in columns `a`, `b`, `c`, in that order"*.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `fcoalesce`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Grossconcat := fcoalesce(Gross, Grossedupnet)]
```